# For each department, retrieve the number of employees who participate in the project "Project 1" or "Project 2"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For each department, retrieve the number of employees who participate in the project "Project 1" or "Project 2"

```
select e.DepartmentID, count(e.DepartmentID) Total
from Employees e
inner join EmployeeProjects ep on e.ID = ep.EmployeeID
inner join Projects p on p.ID = ep.ProjectID
group by e.DepartmentID
having p.Name = 'Project 1' or p.Name = 'Project 2'
```

For my logic this is correct, but why it causing error:

> Column 'Projects.Name' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help to fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If I use `where` then how can I use `group by` ?

Comment: You would improve your question with sample data and desired results (as formatted text **not** images).

Comment: `HAVING` should be applied to **aggregated** column values only - for this, use `WHERE` (which needs to come *before* the `GROUP BY`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your `HAVING` logic to instead appear associated with a left join:

```sql
SELECT e.DepartmentID, COUNT(p.Name) AS Total
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN EmployeeProjects ep ON e.ID = ep.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Projects p
    ON p.ID = ep.ProjectID AND
       p.Name IN ('Project 1', 'Project 2')
GROUP BY e.DepartmentID;
```

We do a left here to the projects table in order to ensure that we don't drop any departments based on project occurrence.  Then, we count the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, an employee could participate in both projects.  Assuming that you want departments even with *no* such employees:

```
select e.DepartmentID,
       count(distinct e.EmployeeID) as Total_projects_12
from Employees e left join
     EmployeeProjects ep
     on e.ID = ep.EmployeeID left join
     Projects p
     on p.ID = ep.ProjectID and
        (p.Name in 'Project 1', 'Project 2')
group by e.DepartmentID;
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is one with group by Project Name, Department and total employees in each department.

```
select p.Name, e.DepartmentID, count(e.EmployeeID) Total
from Employees e inner join EmployeeProjects ep on e.ID = ep.EmployeeID
                 inner join Projects p on p.ID = ep.ProjectID
group by p.Name, e.DepartmentID
having p.Name = 'Project 1' or p.Name = 'Project 2'
```

Comment: Thats not what OP wants though.

Comment: `HAVING` should be applied only to **aggregated** column values (AVG, MIN/MAX, COUNT, SUM)